# Value lookup and rounding questions

Tags: excel, excel-formula, range, lookup, vlookup

I have a cell with a value and I want to lookup that value in a defined range and then grab the closest value in the range that is larger than the lookup cell.

Example:  Cell contains `37.24`, Range has:

```
2.75
5.5
8.25
11
16.5
22
28
34
40
46
...
```

For this instance the formula should return `40` as the value.  If the original field was `40.1` it would return `46`.

Answer (score 2):

If your 'cell' is A1 and the range of values in E3:E12, please try:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A1,E3:E12,1,0),INDEX(E3:E12,MATCH(A1,E3:E12,1)+1))
```

This looks (with VLOOKUP) for an exact match and if that fails uses approximate MATCH to find the next lower value and then INDEX steps down one cell.

Comment: If the lookup range is defined as Array_Sizes, can I use that name instead of the cell range?

Comment: I should also mention that the lookup table is in a different worksheet.